# Add a button to an event to confirm it's done

Tags: fullcalendar

So basically I want to add a button to every event, that changes a value in a php database.
[image]

So in the event in the day view, I want a button that does something when you click! I can't add a button to the event layout. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I can't " ...you mean you've tried something which didn't work, or you don't have any idea how to do it? Either way I suggest you take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender . Once you've read that, you should be able to make some kind of attempt. If you get stuck, add your code to the question, and explain the error/difficulty you're facing.

Comment: I tried some code, with custombuttons but it just broke the view I had. I believe this is on eventRender, but no idea on how to get the buttons in the events.

Comment: Well, if you read the documentation you'll know that the eventRender callback gives you access to the DOM  element which will be added to the calendar in order to show the event. So you just need to append your button HTML to that element

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was thinking, but I tried to do it, but it didn't work. I just don't have an idea on how its done, because for now, I only have the time, title and description showing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I tried to do it, but it didn't work" ... can you please show your attempt. It's impossible to fix invisible code. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. Exactly how it is done will depend which version of fullCalendar you are using. The change between v3 and v4 is quite significant. Make sure you are reading the documentation for your version.